# How to put this layout in CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, android-relativelayout

so i have a layout where i want to display the first three Inputlayouts / EditTexts in 1 CardView... below is my XML and an image whats it looks like right know.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks you very much!! :)

This is my [Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZF7S.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/information"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/field_education_year"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Ausbildungsjahr"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLines="1" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/field_week_start"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="week start"
                        android:inputType="text|date"
                        android:onClick="onClick" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/field_week_end"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="week end"
                        android:inputType="text|date"
                        android:onClick="onClick" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/field_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Title"
                        android:maxLines="1" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/field_notice"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Notice"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_submit_post"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_publish_new_report" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You are using a lot of relativLayouts that can be replaced directly with your TextIputLayout

Comment: @JonathanAste does not help me

Comment: Not the solution you are looking for, but that's why I put this on a comment, just an advice ;)

Comment: @JonathanAste ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, I think everyone would agree that almost every `RelativeLayout` there, is useless. They are doing literally nothing, trust me. You can delete them and it will be exactly the same.

That said, let's move to the point. You want those three `EditText` inside of a `Cardview`, but a `CardView` only contains one child.  You will have to place the `CardView` with a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` inside, and, inside that layout, everything else.

Just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/information"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field_education_year"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Ausbildungsjahr"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field_week_start"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:hint="week start"
                    android:inputType="text|date"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/field_week_end"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:hint="week end"
                    android:inputType="text|date"
                    android:onClick="onClick" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field_notice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Notice"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_submit_post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_publish_new_report" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```